# "Missing separate debuginfo for ..." when running gcore

Tags: libraries, gdb, core-dump

I am running the following:

```
command: gcore 56058

output:
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libdl.so.2
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=dcca9c1f648bda0a7318a7c8844982c440e3e4a3"
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/librt.so.1
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=a8648696e4118ee36ec41c9d75c0520c213ad6ea"
Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=a6fb063da357832cfb5db486b331ab960937c906"
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libm.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=00ad299aa07655131d2732eee1b767b99cf9c85e"
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=9da24cf706b41e55ce5373bcb6253c1618b00abf"
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libpthread.so.0
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=a3bdfa74d39fa9e1c4252ecf5007f7e8c1fcb628"
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x20002407910 (LWP 56067)]
[New Thread 0x20001c07910 (LWP 56066)]
[New Thread 0x20001407910 (LWP 56065)]
[New Thread 0x20000c07910 (LWP 56064)]
[New Thread 0x20000037910 (LWP 56059)]
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libc.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=eeb7bc1f31ca2e17c31f5768901f653e47acd6d3"
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib/ld64.so.1
```

What are the debuginfo's about, what are they cause by and is there any reason for concern? Basically, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilers can be configured to generate extra information with the executable and/or libraries that aid debugging.  With this extra information, your debugger can show the original source code and variable names amongst other things.

Unfortunately, this debugging information take up a lot of space on the system.  Considering that they are hardly ever used (if everything is working to plan) then they are just redundant and take up disk space.

To get around this, many distros split the package into two - one contains everything that is needed to make that package run and the second contains the debug information above.  The latter are called `debuginfo` packages and they need to be installed to successfully debug the main package.

You're using SuSE and as I don't use it, I can't really comment on how to install these packages on that distro other than I believe you enable a repository and use `zypper` to install the same package with `debuginfo` in it's name.

On Fedora you enable a repository and use the `debuginfo-install` command to install these `debuginfo` package.

Your command `gcore` is creating a core dump of process `56058`.  With the `debuginfo` packages installed it could add far more useful debugging info in the core dump, which is why it's suggesting you install them.

Comment: So basically the `debuginfo` are not needed unless actual debugging is necessary as a result of a crash? Also, is there any reason to be worried about those warnings or are they normal?

Comment: True - but why are you generating a core-dump using `gcore` if it's not going to be debugged?  If you've been asked by a developer to send a core-dump then I'm certain they'd prefer one with all the extra info within it.  However, I'm not a developer! Maybe ask them first before installing all the extra packages?